# Autofac + Automapper + custom ValueResolver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper, autofac

Let's say I have custom `ValueResolver`

```
public class AssessmentAttendiesResolver : ValueResolver<List<int>, ICollection<Expert>>
{
    private readonly IRepository<Expert> _expertRepository; 

    public AssessmentAttendiesResolver(IRepository<Expert> expertRepository)
    {
        _expertRepository = expertRepository;
    }

    protected override ICollection<Expert> ResolveCore(List<int> source)
    {
        return (ICollection<Expert>)_expertRepository.Query();
    }
}
```

In my Global.asax I registered my custom resolver and override Mapper.Initialize method like this.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(currentAssembly).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ValueResolver<,>)).AsSelf();

    var container = builder.Build();
    Mapper.Initialize(conf => conf.ConstructServicesUsing(container.Resolve));
```

And `CreateMap` method

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<AssessmentCreateRequestModel, Assessment>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Attendies, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<AssessmentAttendiesResolver>().FromMember(item => item.Attendies));
```

When I run the code I get such exception

> No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself.

What should I change in order to successfully inject my repositories in my custom value resolver?

Comment: Could you show all other related component registrations?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `container.Resolve` to your `Mapper.Initialize` call, which means all of your services will be resolved scoped to the container's lifetime scope. But the error message indicates that it's trying to resolve some service that is registered `InstancePerHttpRequest`.

You need to either change the relevant registrations so that they aren't scoped to the http request, or change the lamba you're passing to `Mapper.Initialize` to that it resolves from the current lifetime scope.

I don't know how when Automapper resolves services and how long it holds onto them to be able to tell you which solution is better. Ideally... *IF* Automapper only resolves services at the moment it needs them, and then immediately forgets about them, then I would recommend using my second solution, otherwise you'll be forced to use the first solution.